# Infinite Ajax Scroll: setting up multiple instances on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

What exactly must be done to set up two instances on the same page?

Have [Infinite AJAX Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) working in a single overflow div but need
to put another overflow div accessing different data on the same
page.

I understand it is possible but cannot find any documentation.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score -1):

You can create two instances, one for each overflow div.

```
// first overflow div
$("#overflow1").ias({
  container:  '.container',
  item:       '.item',
  pagination: '.pagination',
  next:       '.next a',
});

// second overflow div
$("#overflow2").ias({
  container:  '.container',
  item:       '.item',
  pagination: '.pagination',
  next:       '.next a',
});
```

Comment: It works but only once after that the text show on each instance "No more post".